# Autofac instance management?

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, autofac

Lets say I manually instantiate my objects like this:

```
var context = new MyDbContext();
_uow = new UnitOfWork(context);
_repository = new Repository<Account>(context, _uow);
```

Instead, I want to inject them and register them like so:

```
private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync _uow;
private readonly IRepositoryAsync<Account> _repository;

public AccountService(IUnitOfWorkAsync uow, IRepositoryAsync<Account> repository)
{
    _uow = uow;
    _repository = repository;
}
```

Here is the registration.

```
builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().As<IDataContextAsync>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWorkAsync>();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof (Repository<>)).As(typeof (IRepositoryAsync<>));
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AccountService).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(
        i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name));
```

My service gets published to IIS and looks fine, but doesn't function correctly. For example, I go to insert a new Account and it doesn't save to the DB and doesn't error. It seems the injected UnitOfWork is not the same UnitOfWork used to instantiate the repository. I confirmed this with some code in the 
constructor like so:

```
if(_uow.GetHashCode() != _repository.MyUow.GetHashCode())
    throw new ArgumentException("Bad UOW");
```

If I inject the UnitOfWork and repository I ge the exception. If I manually instantiate my objects I do NOT get the exception. I've tried changing my registration to .InstancePerOwned() for the service and other various registration changes to no avail. How do I use Autofac registration to properly instantiate my repository BASED ON the UnitOfWork it already instantiated? I thought the default .InstancePerDependency() would suffice but doens't. Thanks.

---

**Edit 1:** I am using WCF and here is my CustomHostFactory. I don't see an option to specify .InstancePerRequest() like stated in the documentation. Also, interestingly, this line doesn't matter in the below code. Everything works exactly the same if I just take it out. AutofacServiceHostFactory.Container = container;

```
protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
{
    Type contractType = GetContractType(serviceType);

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().As<IDataContextAsync>();
    builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWorkAsync>();

    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof (Repository<>)).As(typeof (IRepositoryAsync<>));

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AccountService).Assembly)
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
        .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(
            i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name));

    var container = builder.Build();
    AutofacServiceHostFactory.Container = container;
    var host = new CustomServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
    host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior(contractType, container);

    return host;
}
private static Type GetContractType(Type serviceType)
{
    return serviceType.GetInterfaces()
        .FirstOrDefault(i => Attribute.IsDefined(i, typeof(ServiceContractAttribute), false));
}
```

Comment: If you register them as `InstancePerRequest` it should work. What kind of application are you building ? WCF services ? If so, did you configure Autofac to work with WCF ? http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/wcf.html

Comment: Yes, it is WCF. I've updated the post to show the CustomServiceHostFactory's CreateServiceHost method. I don't see an option to set the registration as InstancePerRequest.

Comment: 2 steps is needed to configure `Autofac` and `WCF`. You first have to  set the container and change the way `Autofac` knows your service (by modifying your svc file or by adding WCF config, etc. see the documentation for your specific case)

Comment: Yes I know that, I'm using file-less activation (no .svc), with my own CustomServiceHostFactory, which I think is why I'm having issues. I can't find anywhere on the web that shows how to add code to the AutofacServiceHostFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the registrations like so:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().As<IDataContextAsync>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWorkAsync>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepositoryAsync<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AccountService).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(
        i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();
```

As well as setting each of my services to operate per call using the service behavior attribute below:

```
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall
```

Answer (score 0):

InstancePerRequest is only available for WebForms and MVC integration packages.

Try using Autofac integration with WCF in svc.less mode properly, as described below.

[From Autofac docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/wcf.html#svc-less-services):

**Svc-Less Services**

If you want to use services without an .svc file, Autofac will work with that.

As shown above, register your service with the container.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Service1>();
AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();
```

To use svc-less services, add a factory entry under the serviceActivation element in the web.config file. This ensures that the AutofacServiceHostFactory is used to activate the service.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
  <serviceActivations>
    <add factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory"
         relativeAddress="~/Service1.svc"
         service="TestService.Service1" />
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Comment: I've read the documentation. Firstly, where in WCF does that "register your service with the container" code go? Secondly, I want to use CustomServiceHostFactory : AutofacServiceHostFactory. I see no example of that (docs or on web). Is it even possible? Thirdly, I believe the problem is more specific to registration, i.e - using the same UoW in the repository that the container instantiates for the first parameter injected into the AccountService constructor. I'm sorry for "improperly" trying to use Autofac but your regurgitated documentation above doesn't help me "properly" use it.

Comment: Well, I am not quite sure what does this has to do with your custom factory. You need to look closer to your registrations. You register your UoW with per dependency scope. You don't do it explicitly but this is the default scope. Your service has a dependency on UoW and your repository has a dependency on UoW. They get two different versions, your UoW is initialized twice. As mentioned, you have InstancePerRequest extension for MVC integration but this is nothing more than a custom Lifecycle that is created and disposed together with http request.